# Insert into a table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

it doesn't make the register:

```
$reg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO privado (usuario_nombre, titulo, partitura, video, instrumentos, valoracion, votos, descripcion, etiquetas) VALUES ('".$nick."', '".$titulo."', '".$partitura."', '".$video."', '".$instrumentos."', 0, 0, '".$descripcion."', '".$etiquetas."'");                  
                if($reg) {
                    echo "Datos ingresados correctamente.";
                }else {
                    echo "ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos.";
                }
```

It says "ha ocurrido un error..." so $reg is false.

What's wrong?

Thank for your help.

Comment: What error do you get? Add at the end of the query `'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: You should always post the error you have else it is impossible to help you

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the ones you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_POST` data never goes directly in a query.

Comment: @tadman Do you happen to have a raw/literal version of that comment available? xD

Comment: I have a small library of them, but this one is: https://gist.github.com/tadman/9401463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there was a syntax error.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO privado (usuario_nombre, titulo, partitura, video, instrumentos, valoracion, votos, descripcion, etiquetas) VALUES ('".$nick."', '".$titulo."', '".$partitura."', '".$video."', '".$instrumentos."', 0, 0, '".$descripcion."', '".$etiquetas."')");

There was a braket missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you accepted my naswer , and then you take it and accepted for you :) . ok good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this and you can see what the error is and then you can debug it

```
$reg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO privado (usuario_nombre, titulo, partitura, video, instrumentos, valoracion, votos, descripcion, etiquetas) 
                       VALUES ('".$nick."', '".$titulo."', '".$partitura."', '".$video."', '".$instrumentos."', 0, 0, '".$descripcion."', '".$etiquetas."') ") or die(mysql_error());
```